# Two Concurrent instances of Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac, caliburn.micro

I wonder if anyone had ever managed to have two concurrent instances of caliburn micro running in the same app.

In my case I am developing a plugin for an app that accepts plugins but does not run them in separate AppDomains. What I discovered is that Caliburn.Micro cannot be instantiated multiple times because of its reliance on static classes (IoC in particular).

In my case it seems that the best option is to write a layer between Caliburn.Micro and the Containers (I am using Autofac for now) that can pass requests to all the containers but I am not sure this is the best approach.

What I am looking for is a method/plugin/library/(name your here) that is already solving this issue.

Please let me know if you encountered an issue such as this and what solutions you have adopted.